# Count Value Array in conditional if

Tags: arrays, arraylist, count

I have array like this

```
$array =  array( 
           [yes] => 2 
           [no] => 1
);
```

I want to make condition if yes = 3 echo verified, yes = 2 echo fail, else echo fail

here my code

```
if( $array['yes'] = 3 ){
         echo 'verified';

        }elseif( $array['yes'] = 2){
            echo 'warning';
            }else{

                echo 'Fail';
                }
```

I try it but still echo Fail. Hope you can help me. Thank you

EDIT

```
if( $array['yes'] == 3 ){
             echo 'verified';

            }elseif( $array['yes'] == 2){
                echo 'warning';
                }else{

                    echo 'Fail';
                    }
```

I have change = to == but whatever I chenge value array only show' verified'

Comment: If it's PHP you have a syntax error in your array declaration : it miss a `,` between first and second line, and you have to replace `[` and `]` by `'` and `'`

Answer (score 0):

the comparison in many (if not all) languages is `==` and not `=`

when you are doing  `if( $array['yes'] = 3 )` you are actually assigning `3` to `$array['yes']`. To check if it's equal to something, you have to write
`if( $array['yes'] == 3 )`

so :

```
if( $array['yes'] == 3 ) {
  echo 'verified';
} elseif( $array['yes'] == 2) {
  echo 'warning';
} else {
  echo 'Fail';
}
```

Comment: thank you,  I have try that but only echo first one,  every time array change it's only echo verified even yes => 3

Comment: did you use double `==` and not single `=` ?
Is it php ?  Chek it out, it works : http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/49dbf572ca2622efae9721fbf2f4f3b42012d59b